# Solution to the differential equation: $y''-xy^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the differential equation (where, $y$ is a function of $x$):
$$ y''-xy^2=0 $$
I did the following substitution and got:
$$ v=y',  y''=v\frac{dv}{dy}$$
Which I then substituted into my original equation and separated it to yield:
$$vdv=xy^2dy$$
What I am confused about, is if it is okay to integrate both sides, or, since $x$ can be written as a function of $y$, would this method be invalid? That is to say, would the integral of the right hand side be:
$$x\frac{y^3}{3}+c$$ or something else, since $x$ could be written as a function of $y$? If so, then by what method could I solve the differential equation?

Comment: This method only works for autonomous DE, with no extra $x$. What kind of solution is expected? There will likely not exist a solution in terms of "known" functions.

Comment: So, the integral of the RHS is not simply: $$x\frac{y^{3}}{3}+c$$

Comment: Also, how would you solve the ODE then?

Comment: "How would you solve the ODE then?" ${\leftarrow }$ it's important to note, most ODE's do not have "nice solutions" you can write down. Many do have solutions, but not in terms of functions we use on a day to day basis. If you want to solve ${y'' = xy^2}$, you are likely going to have to resort to numerical methods

Comment: Saying ${\int xy^2dy = x\int y^2dy}$ is not a valid step, since $x$ and $y$ are not independent from each other unfortunately

Comment: Use a series solution